# Susy 2 Grid in Grid

Tags: css, grid, sass, susy-compass

I have the following grids defined:

```
$main-grid: 12 (remCalc(62.4166667px) remCalc(20px)) after static float
$twelve-fluid: 12 remCalc(15px) after fluid float

+set-grid($main-grid)
```

The `$main-grid` is being set on my `.container`. I wish the `$twelve-grid` to be set on a child of `.container` called `.container__main` so I have the following:

```
+use-grid($twelve-fluid)
  .container__main
    +rem(padding, 20px)
    background-color: #ffffff
    +background-image(linear-gradient(top, #c4c3b1, #ffffff remCalc(30px)))
    +background-image(linear-gradient(top, #c4c3b1, #ffffff 30px))
    +background-grid
```

The things that are wrong is that the grid does not fit inside the 20px (or rem equivalent) padding that `.container__main` has. How can I get it to adapt to that so the grid of 12 fluid columns fits inside.

I also tried replacing `+background-grid` with `+overlay-grid` but I don't seem to get any output whatsoever?

The rem pixel width fallbacks are still not showing up. Is this in the pipeline? (Not rushing, just so I know).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add background-origin and -clip. Those will be added automatically in the next pre-release, but for now you have to add them by hand:

```
.container__main
  +background-origin(content-box)
  +background-clip(content-box)
```

That will clip your other backgrounds as well, so you could wrap it in a mixin. Something like this:

```
@mixin show-grid($show: $show-grids)
  @if $show and $show != hide
    +background-grid
    +background-origin(content-box)
    +background-clip(content-box)

.container__main
  +show-grid
```

That's just a temporary workaround - part of using the alpha. We already have it fixed in the susy-next branch, and we'll have it out in a new gem very soon.

Comment: Ok, So do the widths of items being laid out using that sub grid, $twelve-grid in this case, do they take note of the surrounding padding and it's just the grid background that needs fixing?

How about the overlay grid and fallbacks issues?

Comment: Yes, background grids need help with padding, but actual elements lay out just fine with or without the padding. I don't know how you are using overlay-grid, or what you've tried, so I can't speak to that. And Susy Next doesn't yet have support for rem-fallbacks.